# Displaying dynamically sorted divs/data in Vue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vue.js, computed-properties

I'm trying to figure out how to create a drop-down menu that sorts a dynamically rendered (thru a for loop) div filled with different data (interestRates,loanAmounts)

```
<div class="sortedByDiv">sorted by 
  <select class="sortingFont"> 
    <option>Monthly Cost</option>
    <option>Interest Rate</option>
    <option>Loan Amount</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Ideally, clicking through the select options in the above drop-down menu will 'trigger' the method that renders the sorted data. The current code I have that shows viewers the unsorted data is shown below:

```
<div class="wrapper1" v-for="product in products">
  <div class="logoDiv"><img :src="product.logo"/>
    {{product.interestRate.ir}}
    {{product.amount | currency}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I made some computed methods to do the sorting below:

```
computed: {

sortedProductsInterestRate: function() {
  var interestArr = new Array
  for (let item1 of this.products) {
    if (item1.interestRate.ir != null) {  
      interestArr.push(item1.interestRate.ir)
      interestArr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    }
  }
  return interestArr
},
# also have same concept for {{product.amount}}
```

My main problem and question is that I don't know how to change that bit that renders the products in a div via a for-loop. I want to change that to display the "new" divs, sorted based on the select options at the top.

Comment: Here's a quick example: https://codesandbox.io/s/olq30v7yk6

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) the `<select>`'s value to a local data property (e.g., named `filter`) that the `filteredProducts` [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) uses to calculate the `products` to display. Note that Vue automatically re-evaluates the computed property when it detects a change in any of its dependencies (any data property used).

Here are the steps:

1. Create a data property to store the filter value (from `<select>`)

   - `filter` - (string) the selected filter
2. Create a dictionary of `filter`-to-sorter-function. We'll use the `filter` data property to lookup a sorter for `this.allProducts.sort()`.

   ```
   const sorters = {
     monthlyCost: (a,b) => a.monthlyCost - b.monthlyCost,
     interestRate: (a,b) => a.interestRate.ir - b.interestRate.ir,
     loanAmount: (a,b) => a.amount - b.amount,
   };
   ```
3. Create a computed property that [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)s `this.products` (to create a copy) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)s the result, using a sorter function based on the selected `filter`.

   ```
   computed: {
     filteredProducts() {
       return this.products.slice().sort(sorters[this.filter]);
     }
   }
   ```
4. Change the template so that `v-for` iterates this computed property:

   ```
   <div v-for="product in filteredProducts">
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq397npryq)

Comment: in your code example, you have array allProducts "pre-loaded" with 4 pieces of fakeData(). I need to make a similar array but I can't hardcode that fakeData() bit... it comes from an API and is accessed via this.products... How do i make a full unfiltered collection of products as an array if this is the case? @tony19

Comment: Just rename `allProducts` to `products`, and `products` to `filteredProducts`. Then, in your template, change `v-for="product in products"` to `v-for="product in filteredProducts"`. I've updated the answer to show this.

Comment: @Jorr.it `sort()` mutates the original array, which is a side effect. Computed props should not have side effects. `slice()` creates a copy to be sorted, which avoids the side effect.